# Delete next camelcase word segment?

Tags: eclipse, camelcasing

I frequently use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> command to delete the next word.

I was wondering, is there an equivalent keyboard combination in Eclipse to delete the next word in a camelcase word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> deletes up to the next camel case word border, not whitespace word border (in the Java editor).

So for deletion of the next camel case word part you could use the sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right/Left</kbd> (position before current or next camel case word part), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Weird, I can't remember what prompted me to post this.  One would think would have tried it before writing the question.  Maybe I was using a different language at the time or perhaps I was SO'ing with Ambien?

Comment: I'm writing Python code currently in Eclipse and this feature does not work the same as it does in Java. Do you have any idea how to change that functionality to match the above?