# Deleting camel humps in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, camelcasing

I want to be able to delete camel humps (i.e. camel case word segments) in IntelliJ e.g. using Ctrl+Delete/Ctrl+Backspace.

Apparently, this is possible in Eclipse, as per below post, but I am unable to find how to do it in IntelliJ

[Delete next camelcase word segment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999661/delete-next-camelcase-word-segment)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check below:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-smart-keys.html

IntelliJ IDEA also provides similar actions that work in a mode opposite to the one selected in the Use 'CamelHumps' words setting:

Move Caret to Previous Word in Different "CamelHumps" mode

Move Caret to Previous Word with Selection in Different "CamelHumps" mode

Move Caret to Next Word in Different "CamelHumps" mode

Move Caret to Next Word with Selection in Different "CamelHumps" mode

Delete to Word End in Different "CamelHumps" mode

Delete to Word Start in Different "CamelHumps" mode

For example, if Use 'CamelHumps' words is enabled, the action Move Caret to Next Word in Different "CamelHumps" mode moves the caret to the end of word regardless of uppercase characters in this word; if Use 'CamelHumps' words is disabled, then the caret moves to the next CamelHump within this word.